# issue in jokykong/sidemenu changing back button

Tags: ios, swift, side-menu

I'm using jonkykong/sidemenu for iOS apps, swift , https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

**My issue:**

when I open the side menu and navigate to a child controller from the side menu, the side menu icon is changing and becoming the icon I provide in the child menu controller ,I want it to stay as the side menu icon, and keeps it's action in toggling the side menu not navigating back home.

**note:**

I know i can do it on my own by customizing the child controller and adding the toggle action, but I'm asking if there is a feature , for this purpose in this library.

This is the home screen :

[image]

This is the side menu open:

[image]

This is the child screen:

[image]

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the relevant code causing the issue in the form of a [mcve] to make your question on topic.

Comment: you can clone the library from here to check my issue, it's in the example project, 
https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu.